# Undo Chrome browser reset to defaults

Tags: google-chrome

1. Signed into Chrome browser
2. Reset to default settings
3. All my extensions disappeared

### Questions

- How can I restore/re-enable my extensions? (The extensions were not uninstalled)
- Does settings reset remove anything other than just extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reset default settings - what does this do?

> The following settings will change back to the default:
>
> - Default search engine, which is changed back to Google. Learn how to set your default search engine.
> - Homepage and tabs. Learn how to set your Chrome homepage and set default startup tabs.
> - The new tab page. Learn how to set the page that a new tab opens to.
> - Tabs you have pinned. Learn how to pin tabs.
> - Content settings, like letting a site show you pop-ups or use your microphone. Learn how to change your content settings.
> - Cookies and site data, like items in an online shopping cart. Learn more about cookies and site data.
> - Extensions and themes. Learn more about extensions and themes.
>
> Only the settings for the Chrome profile you're signed in to will be
>   reset. Your new settings will apply across all computers or devices
>   where you’re signed in to your active profile.

Source [Reset Chrome settings to default](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en)

---

#### How can I restore/re-enable extensions?

You will need to install them again.

Comment: I was hoping to find the file location of the configurations, and restore those files, but I had to reinstall everything,

Answer (score 0):

it was a long time ago but it might have used the reset while having multiple chrome users, and I think it might have removed all the other users also...  and what I had to do was to just add each chrome user back and confirm the syncronization, than everything was back to normal.